# Solving a variation of the knapsack in which the value of an item depends on items that are already in the sack

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to solve the following problem:
I have a set of `N` items, where each pair of items have a mutual score, and I need to select a combination of `W` items such that the overall score is the greatest.
The overall score of items `i,j,k` for example is

```
score(i,j) + score(i,k) + score(j,k).
```

In order to avoid going through all `N^W` possible combinations, I thought about doing a variation on the `0-1` knapsack problem and solve with dynamic programing with these 2 changes:

1. Set  all weights to equal 1 (so eventually I will get exactly `W` items in my sack)
2. Instead of having an array of constant value per item I will calculate the values "on the fly" according to the current item being checked and the items already in the sack at that point.

I already started coding the solution with these two changes, however now that I think about it more I'm afraid that it can't be solved with dynamic programing since the "optimal substructure" property doesn't hold.
For instance, if `W=3` and items `i,j,k` is the optimal solution, then for `W=2`, `i,j` is not necessarily an optimal solution (according to the calculation of overall score above).
Does anybody have an idea how this problem can be solved with dynamic programing and not with `O(N^W)` brute force?

Thanks

Comment: You can definitely use DP to save all the mutual scores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is NP-hard, which means there is almost certainly no fast polynomial time algorithm to solve it, because no one has been able to come up with a polynomial time algorithm to solve an NP-hard problem. To see NP-hardness, suppose you have a graph where nodes are your indices and you define the score between i,j to be 1 if there is an edge between i and j, otherwise 0. Then if you can, in polynomial time, find the maximum score subset of nodes that have at most W nodes included, then you can, in polynomial time, figure out if there is a clique of size W in your graph. This is an NP-complete problem.